# Почему необходимо инициализировать коллекции именно так?

Tags: java, коллекции

Почему коллекции необходимо создавать таким образом:

```
List list = new Linkedlist();
```

Почему нежелательно сразу писать `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Это важный прием написания хорошего ООП кода. Идея в том что так ваш код становится менее зависим от конкретных реализаций используемых модулей. В тот же самый интерфейс `List` можно записать `LinkedList`, `ArrayList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` и т.д.

При этом, объявив список подобным образом, мы можем быть уверены что если вдруг появится необходимость подменить реализацию с `LinkedList` на `ArrayList`, то нам придется изменить только строчку с вызовом конструктора. Например `LinkedList`, в отличии от `ArrayList`, помимо интерфейса `List` имплементирует ещё `Queue`(очередь) в котором есть метод push.

```
List list = new LinkedList();
LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

list.add("ok");
linkedList.add("ok");
arrayList.add("ok");

list.push("error"); //ошибка при компиляции, у интерфейса List нет такого метода.
linkedList.push("Ok");
arrayList.push("error"); //ошибка при компиляции, ArrayList не имплементирует Queue
```

В примере выше, даже не смотря на то что в `list` у нас хранится экземпляр `LinkedList`, мы не можем вызвать специфичные для него методы. Интерфейс `List` вынуждает нас пользоваться только методами списка, а не очереди или чего-либо ещё.

Использование интерфейса вместо реализации не столь важно когда коллекция(или другой объект) создаётся и используется внутри одного метода, но важно если она каким-либо образом передаётся в другие модули.

Подробнее на эту тему читайте про **SOLID**.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Все стало понятно.

Comment: Это важно для типов параметров, но не для локальных переменных. В чём польза именно для локальных переменных?

Comment: @Qwertiy т.е. код еще и теряет функционал(методы LL например) при написании List`a?
А можно сначала написать List list = new LinckedList(); , а потом когда понадобятся мeтоды из LL переопределить как-нибудь?

Comment: @антонсорокин, да, если у него есть особенные методы, не входящие в интерфейс.

Answer (score 6):

`List` — это интерфейс, а `LinkedList` - это класс, который имплементирует этот интерфейс. `interface List` содержит базовые методы `add(), get(), remove()` и так далее, если тебе достаточно этих методов можешь писать `List<...> list = new LinkedList<..>()`, если нужно использовать доп. методы которые есть в классе `LinkedList` тогда следует писать так `LinkedList<...> linkedList = new LinkedList<...>();`

Comment: Может наоборот? LinkedList это интерфейс List?и мне кажется, что тут явно есть причина почему нужно писать именно так, как я написал в примере.

Comment: @Nojdon, нет, не наоборот. Нельзя создать инстанс интерфейса.

Comment: @Qwertiy сдается мне ТС имел в виду почему лучше писать `List list = new Linkedlist();` а не `Linkedlist list = new Linkedlist();`

Comment: @Qwertiy, а причём тут экземпляр интерфейса? Я говорю про то, что list это главный интерфейс, если точнее, то коллекция. И именно от него все другие коллекции имплеметируются

Comment: @Nojdon, `List` - это интерфейс, насколько я помню. `LinkedList` - класс, реализующий этот интерфейс. `LinkedList` не может быть интерфейсом, поскольку `new Linkedlist()` создаёт экземпляр, а экземпляр интерфейса создать нельзя. Поэтому утверждение _"LinkedList это интерфейс List"_ неверно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я отвечал на его комментарий _"Может наоборот? LinkedList это интерфейс List?"_, а не на вопрос.

Comment: обновил ответ, теперь думаю стало яснее.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты захочешь из базы подтянуть какие-то сущности, которые в твоих репозиториях будут сохранятся как разные листы, тебе придется как минимум каждый раз чекать модель, чтобы посмотреть какой же там лист. А инициализируя через интерфейс ты на несколько секунд упрощаешь свою жизнь. 
Это один из примеров и таких можно навести еще много. К примеру, если ты изменил в модели лист с array на linked, но в сервисах или контроллерах подтягивал сущности именно в array, тогда тебе придется в ручную все изменять, но иницилизируя от интерфейса эта потребность отпадает.

Answer (score -1):

Потому что это идеология джавы, объявлять переменные с типами интерфейса.

Но скоро это изменится:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/280188/
https://habrahabr.ru/post/280075/

```
val list = new Linkedlist();
```

Comment: Вот такой ответ меня и устраивает. Спасибо за конкретность и отдельно за ссылки.

Comment: А вот мне бы хотелось знать почему)) Ведь вопрос в этом. Почему они решили так, а не иначе. Не монетку же кидали. Есть этому какое-то правильное обдуманное объяснение на чем-то основанное

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - Потому что код надо писать в наиболее общем виде. Если дальнейшему коду достаточно типа `List`, то и переменную надо объявлять как `List` - так близко к базовому типу как это возможно.

Comment: Хорошо бы var, а ещё getter-ы n setter-ы как в c#. Про них ничего не слышно?

Comment: @Sergey, я не джавист.