# Интерфейсы, коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции, интерфейс

Доброго времени суток. Есть класс с полями, он имлементирует интерфейс с некоторыми методами. В новой классе создается список. Возможна ли следующая запись создания списка(1). Если да, то как обращаться к элементу такого списка?

```
 public interface MyInt{
  void getSmth();
  }

 public class MyClass implements MyInt{
  public String name;
  public Integer age;

  @Override
  public void get(){
  ....
   }

  public class Work{
 (1) private static List<MyInt> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: `Возможна ли следующая запись создания списка` - в принципе так и создаются списки и объекты......... `как обращаться к элементу такого списка?` - а что именно смущает? можно по индексу брать, к примеру.

Comment: просто не обычно что на основе интерфейса создается коллекция, и как например заполнить такую коллекцию.

Comment: по поводу "необычно" - [Почему необходимо инициализировать коллекции именно так?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/513092/191482) ...........`как например заполнить такую коллекцию` - как обычно, например `list.add(new MyClass())` только желательно конструктор иметь у MyClass, чтоб инициализировать поля сразу

Comment: я имею в виду что в <> интерфейс ничего не имеющий в себе

Comment: там не интерфейс.................. в нужный момент, когда необходимы методы класса MyClass нужно просто "кастовать" к нему, например `System.out.println(((MyClass)list.get(0)).name);`

Answer (score 1):

Возможна, но если у интерфейса нет ничего полезного - не имеет большого смысла, так вам придется явно приводить интерфейс к классу, а это считается плохим кодом.

```
private static List<MyInt> list = new LinkedList<>();

private static void main(...) {
     list.add(new MyClass());
     list.add(new MyClass());
     MyClass obj = (MyClass) list.get(0); // плохой код (даже при проверки перед этим на instanceof)
     String name = obj.getName();
}
```

Намного правильнее сделать новый интерфейс в котором будут все нужные поля или просто хранить MyClass вместо интерфейса. Если вам в коллекции нужны только методы интерфейса, то все проще

```
private static void main(...) {
     list.add(new MyClass());
     list.add(new MyClass());
     MyInt obj = list.get(0); // нормальный код
     obj.getSmth();
}
```

Comment: Когда кастование стало признаком плохого кода?

Comment: Если в нем нет смысла - всегда. Какой смысл от статических типов, если вы получаете ошибки в рантайме и какой смысл от наследования и интерфейсов, если вы начинаете кастовать вручную? Да иногда без него не обойтись, но всегда когда есть возможность решить задачу без кастования - лучше решать без. То есть варнинги в Java при кастовании для вас хороший тон? А вариниг в случае выше будет;

Comment: Если класс реализует несколько интерфейсов и имеет свои поля и методы, а в какой-то момент нужно пробежаться по коллекции объектов которые реализуют конкретный интерфейс, но вытащив параллельно поля класса - рекомендуете в каждом интерфейсе насоздавать поля такие на всякий случай? Не кажется это ерундой?

Comment: 1) тут стоит подумать. а точно ли нужна такая коллекция мало связанных объектов? Может лучше иметь несколько коллекций конкретных классов или HashMap<тип, коллекция> 2) это как раз тот случай, когда плохо, но придется использовать кастинг. Пока этого можно избежать - лучше избегать

Comment: `Вытащив параллельно поля класса` - какого класса? Всё, что гарантирует коллекция - объявленный интерфейс, знание того, какие конкретно объекты там лежат - признак плохой архитектуры.

Comment: В соседнем ответе привел ссылки за статьи известных авторов, википедию (знаю, что не все ей доверяют, но там тоже есть список источников) на русском и английском

Comment: Кастование  - признак плохого кода просто потому, что тут 2 варианта: 1)вы кастуете заранее зная, что к родителю приведены объекты одного класса, тогда смысла в интерфейсе нет, потому как это фактически означает, что интерфейс импелементирует единственный класс, но при этом интерфейс на вмещает всех методов этого класса, это старнно, 2) у вас много наследников и вы кастуете,но теперь вы просто не знаете, что именно за объект приведен к интерфейсу,а значит у вас в коде появляется один из самых медленных операторов инстансоф.Чем больше потомков,тем больше свитч инстансоф, так до бесконечности...

Answer (score 1):

Дурной тон - не проверять ситуацию приведения типа, когда подставляете код, под исключение времени выполнения, если этого можно избежать.

```
public class Test {

    public interface InterfaceX {
        public void iMethod();
    }

    public static class A implements InterfaceX {

        public void methodA() {
            System.out.println("call methodA()");
        }

        public void iMethod() { System.out.println("call iMethod from A"); }

    }

    public static class B implements InterfaceX {

        public void iMethod() { System.out.println("call iMethod from B"); }

    }

    public static List<InterfaceX> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String...args) {
        list.add(new A());
        list.add(new B());
        for(InterfaceX item : list) {
            //надо проверять, когда существует такая возможность
            //java.lang.ClassCastException
            //((A) item).methodA();
            if(item instanceof A)
                ((A) item).methodA();
            item.iMethod(); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Все равно плохой код, которого стоит избегать пока это возможно (это не мое мнение, а многих известных авторов Peter Haggar, Scott Meyers, Bill Venners):
http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html 
http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html
https://books.google.pl/books?id=iWPeqljHNcoC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=instanceof+and+downcasting+java+avoid&source=bl&ots=ObDMNMchjO&sig=3FayOr2tfg2CMQGJwrwJyckebwM&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY5O7ho57XAhUL0hoKHQ7LC3YQ6AEIaTAI#v=onepage&q=instanceof%20and%20downcasting%20java%20avoid&f=false

Comment: Еще ссылок:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting
http://www.yegor256.com/2015/04/02/class-casting-is-anti-pattern.html
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: Вопрос не в том, чтобы подставиться под класскаст, а вопрос в том, как рационально и правильно использовать интерфейсы. Это случай их кривого использования. И на этот костыль теперь, разумеется, придется прикрутить другой костыль - в виде проверки каста... Вот и все.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, с чем именно вы пытаетесь разобраться... Если вы хотите понять, зачем нужен интерфейс, то это плохой пример, так Вы ничего не поймете. У интерфейсов есть несколько назначений.
Во-первых, это уровень абстракций. Чтобы понять это присмотритесь к интерфейсу List и классам, его имплементирующим. Идея в том, что общий родитель всегда дает Вам пользоваться ООП в полную силу. Полиморфизм, наследование немыслимы без этого. Дополнительный уровень абстракций в этом смысле дает вам возможность писать более универсальный код, если можно так выразиться. Представьте, что вы пишите метод, на входе вы принимаете коллекцию. И тут у вас есть выбор... Если вы примите одну из конкретных реализаций, например ArrayList, то больше ни с чем Ваш метод работать и не сможет. Если вы напишите метод, принимающий List, то теперь можно использовать его сразу с несколькими наследниками, Вам все равно с какими именно. Ну а если вы примите Collection, то Ваш метод совсем универсальный и из всех стандартных коровых коллекций не принимает разве что Maр. 
Во-вторых, есть GRASP-паттерн Low Coupling. Плюсы этого в том, что код становится гибким и легко изменяемым. Идея в том, чтобы между вашими классами было как можно меньше связей. Этим, кстати, пользуется спринг. И это называется слабая ссылка. Такой код реализуется именно с помощью интерфейсов. Любой из классов имплементирует свой интерфейс, а другие классы обращаются именно с интерфейсами. Тогда изменения в классах никак не касаются других классов, ведь они взаимодействуют исключительно с интерфейсами. Стоит импелементировать какой-либо из интерфейсов и Вы можете даже подменить Ваш класс, а программа при этом будет и дальше работать, не нуждаясь ни в каких изменениях.
В-третьих,интерфейсы помогают при разделении обязанностей при написании приложения в команде. Предположим, Вам надо четко разделить обязанности, но полагаться на память других участников команды в плане того, что именно они должны сделать, глупо. Член команды может просто забыь реализовать нужный метод. неправильно его называть, вернуть значение не того типа и т.д. Поэтому можно написать ряд интерфейсов и каждый из участников реализует именно определенный набор интерфейсов. Все компоненты взаимодействуют на уровне интерфейсов и никаких проблем не возникает.
В Вашем случае у интерфейса только один метод и один класс, его импелементирующий. Разумеется , если Вам нужен только этот метод, то все нормально. В остальном в данном конкретном локальном примере приведение этого класса к инетрфейсу не имеет смысла.