# Почему полиморфизм это удобно?

Tags: java, полиморфизм

На собеседовании по java спросили - зачем писать, к примеру,

```
Фигура треугольник = new Треугольник(),
```

а не просто

```
Треугольник треугольник = new Треугольник()
```

и почему это удобно?

Comment: Из-за абстракции?

Comment: Низачем. Это не имеет значения.

Comment: @free_ze, [tag:php] o_O? Скорее уж это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/513092/178988, но я не уверен.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я думаю здесь больше вопрос по терминологии, чем по языку программирования.

Comment: @Qwertiy, полиморфизм там тоже есть, да) Соль вопроса в теории, а php - такой себе псевдокод.

Answer (score 9):

Можно здесь много антимоний развести, конечно: что это ни фига не полиморфизьм, что это вообще не об этом, что это и т.д.

Отвечу так:

1. Когда пишем: `Фигура треугольник = new Треугольник()`, мы подразумеваем, что треугольник рассматриваем как наследник класса `Фигура` (ну или что `Треугольник` реализует интерфейс `Фигура`)
2. Что подразумевает, что методы класса/интерфейса `Фигура` реализованы в классе `Треугольник` (например `Фигура.площадь()` - реализуется в разных классах по разному)
3. Кроме этого мы неявно подразумеваем, что возможно где-то есть класс(ы) `Четырехугольник`, `Многоугольник` или даже `Серо-буро-малиновый-овал`, которые также наследники класса `Фигура`
4. Все это вместе дает нам право сказать, что вместо `Треугольник` мы переходим на другой уровень абстракции `Фигура` и можем например рассматривать не отдельные коллекции треугольников, многоугольников, а сразу 1 коллекцию фигур - ну и т.д. и т.п.
5. Далее переходим к заключении, что написавший сию строку прогер - невероятно крут и умеет абстрактно мыслить и все такое прочее.

Answer (score 2):

Конкретно в указанном вами примере - практически ничем.

Если это определение локальной переменной в каком-то методе(вероятней всего так), то правильным ответом будет "потому что в компании принято соглашение писать именно так" - ни о каких "удобствах" тут и речи быть не может- просто субьективное предпочтение людей составлявших это самое соглашение.

Если же подразумевалось определение приватного поля класса, то конкретно в случае с Java, насколько помню - в сабкласе после вызова конструктора можно будет подменить этот объект на любой другой объект, реализующий интерфейс `Треугольник` или являющийся наследником одноименного класса - крайне редко необходимая возможность, в общем-то..