# Почему экземпляры HashMap иногда создают с типом Map?

Tags: java, map, интерфейс, hashmap

Чем отличается строка:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

от

```
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Я понимаю, что класс `HashMap` расширяет интерфейс `Map`, но мне интересно именно, почему в одних случаях нужно делать так как в первой строке, а в других так, как во второй.
И в каких случаях нужно применять первый способ, а каких второй?

Comment: если коротко - `HashMap`  слева нужно писать когда вы хотите в дальнейшем обращаться к методам и полям определенным в `HashMap`, но не в `Map`

Comment: вы случайно аргументы местами поменяли или это и есть суть вопроса?

Comment: @ tim bars, аргументы и правда поменял местами случайно, но в данном случае это особо не важно, спасибо, что заметили, отредактирую

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему необходимо инициализировать коллекции именно так?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/513092/204271)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему необходимо инициализировать коллекции именно так?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513092/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Экземпляр `HashMap` стоит помещать в переменную типа `Map`, для того чтобы каждый раз при обращении к `HashMap`-специфичным методам (методам которые определяются в `HashMap`) вам не приходилось приводить `Map` переменную к `HashMap` типу:

```
(HashMap)myMap.superSpecificHashMapMethod();
```

P.S. `HashMap` не расширяет интерфейс `Map`, а реализует/имлементирует его.

Answer (score 1):

Использование интерфейса в объявлении переменной оправдано, если в ней могут быть использованы разные наследники. Примеры можно встретить в шаблонах проектирования (например, фабричный метод).
Также некоторые фреймворки требуют использование интерфейсов в определении переменной. Например, если в сущности Hibernate вы объявите переменную как HashMap, Hibernate ругнется, что не может использовать этот тип. Ведь для вашей коллекции ему необходимо подставить прокси объект (свою реализацию), поэтому нужно использовать Map. Возможно в вашем случае преимущество использования Map вместо HashMap не очевидно, но это хорошая практика и лучше её придерживаться, дабы вошло в привычку.