# Вопрос по полиморфизму/ наследованию

Tags: java, ооп

Условно у нас есть суперкласс A и подкласс B. Не раз в чужом коде замечал, что создавая объект класса В, пишут следующее:

1. A object = new B();
   а не
2. B obj = new B();

Какой смысл от данного действия, если после подобного создания,у нашего объекта мы потеряем доступ к полям и методам именно класса В? Что мы выигрываем от такого, если объявив бы по варианту 2, мы бы все равно могли бы впихнуть свой объект в условный метод test(A obj);

Comment: Один из вариантов - чтобы подчеркнуть, что B методы не нужны, нужен именно А и неважно какой. Если надо, потом легко будет подменить B на C, который тоже наследник A.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему необходимо инициализировать коллекции именно так?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513092/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba)

Comment: Где-то ещё подобные дубликаты были....но смысл понятен

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как на практике применяется полиморфизм?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935362/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc)